# Export security description data from bloomberg into excel

Tags: fixed-income, bloomberg, excel

I have the cusip of about 300 bonds. I want to retrieve the security description from bloomberg and then export it into excel. Does anyone have any tips as to how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi @bondzgu3st and welcome to quant.SE! You could ask to the help desk for this kind of information. Surely, you should get more precise information by them! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the description you can use `=BDP(TICKER,"CIE DES")` directly in Excel.